# How to increase performance of bash scripts called by child_process's

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process, pdftotext

I'm working with `pdftotext` to extract text from multiple PDF 's in parallel,
using a mix of `child_process.spawn` and `async.mapLimit` to limit the number of concurrence.

My question is regarding performance. I get a little lost in relation to CPU intensive work.
I'm opening the processes using `Node.js`, it means I'm doing CPU intensive
 with `Node.js` (since it is his child process), or I'm doing with bash?

Is there any way to improve performance? Often the program takes up hours to complete a job, because the amount of files + their size . Frankly I do not know very much about bash, is there anything I can do to improve the parallel processing?

Comment: [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel)?

Comment: or `xargs`. It also depends on if your system is well balanced in CPU/RAM/Disk AND that the systems are functioning well. If you're relying on a SAN disk array, you'll want to be sure that it is functioning correctly. (Sorry I can't give you an easy test for that, but try benchmarking `gzip -c 1GBfile > /mount/path/1/1GBfile.gz` to numerous subsections of your `/mount` filesystem and note which ones take significantly longer than a local disk. (This is the subject of a multi-part magazine article, so put on your thinking cap ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: You could try to use .exec .execFile or .fork instead of .spawn. I believe spawn is most appropriate if you have large single tasks.
https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try to use .exec, .execFile or .fork instead of .spawn. I believe spawn, which you're using, is most appropriate if you have large single tasks.
   See: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node
2. Run the system monitor tool `top` or `htop` and observe your CPU consumption while the processing is running: are all cores maxed out? This way you can determine if CPU is your current bottleneck.
3. It may be that pdftotext is inherently slow. Can you find a faster library or switch from Node to something else? An indication of a fast Node library might be that the library is just a set of C bindings.